# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined---Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

how are you?
I have one problem  'slice' of undefined in my project. I use autocomplete material https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

My code.ts
//get all Country from webservice

```
this.ws.AllCountry().subscribe(
      countryes => {
        this.countryes = countryes.map((country) => {
          return new Country(country);
        });
      }
    );
```

// Create FilterOptions

```
   this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredOptionsCountry = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(country =>  country ? this.filterCountry(country) : this.countryes.slice()) // Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    );
```

// filter country

```
 filterCountry(name: string) {
    return this.countryes.filter(country =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
```

Code.html

```
 <form class="example-form">
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input matInput placeholder="Select Country" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredOptionsCountry | async" [value]="country.country_id">
           {{ country.name }}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
     </mat-form-field>
   </form>
```

Can you suggest me some idea, what is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: The message is telling where the error is... `countryes` is apparently `undefined`, you need to debug your code ;)

Comment: if you can reproduce this would be easy in like stackblitz or something

Comment: `slice()` requires parameters
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: slice() is equal to slice(0)

Answer (score 0):

i think you're using countryes before it's defined inside subscription, i suggest to move your "Create FilterOptions" code inside allCountry subscription where countryes is defined

Comment: Create FilterOptions is inside constructor. and this.ws.AllCountry().subscribe( ) is inside  ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

map((country: string | null) => country ? this._filter(country) : this.countryes.slice()));